# Searching a file and storing it in a variable php

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have a text file that goes like this

```
1 wordsgohere
2 morewordsgohere
3 yougetthepoint
```

I want to assign one of the strings above to the user_id of that person. So say you are the third person to register, your user_id is 3 and your deposit_id would be 'yougetthepoint'. However when I echo user_id it's always 0 even though there are 2 or three users in the database and when looking at the database the id number increases. It won't put the user in the data base either. If I replace deposit_id with something else it will put the user in the data base. I think it's because new_str never gets defined.

```
    // id of new user
    $user_id = $this->db_connection->lastInsertId();

    echo $user_id;

    // searches text file for address
    $lines_array = file("test.txt");

    foreach($lines_array as $line) {
    echo $line;
            if(strpos($line, $user_id) != false) {
                    list(, $new_str) = explode($user_id, $line);

            }
    }


    // write new users data into database
    $query_new_user_insert = $this->db_connection->prepare('INSERT INTO users (deposit_id, user_name, user_password_hash, user_email, user_activation_hash, user_registration_ip, user_registration_datetime) VALUES(:deposit_id, :user_name, :user_password_hash, :user_email, :user_activation_hash, :user_registration_ip, now())');
    $query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':deposit_id', $new_str, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':user_name', $user_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':user_password_hash', $user_password_hash, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':user_email', $user_email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':user_activation_hash', $user_activation_hash, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':user_registration_ip', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $query_new_user_insert->execute();
```

Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: You're calling `lastInsertId()` before you do the `INSERT`. Do you expect it to predict the future?

Comment: `list(, $new_str) = $line` can't work. When you use `list()`, the value has to be an array, not a string. Did you mean to call `explode()`?

Comment: Your `strpos()` check is no good. If `$user_id` is `3` and `$line` is `13 something`, it will match. You should explode the line, and compare the user ID with the first element of the array.

Comment: You should use the `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` option to `file()`, otherwise `$line` will have a newline character at the end, which you probably don't want.

Comment: @Barmar But if I put it after insert, the user will be inserted before I can make it decide what value to store for deposit_id. any suggestions? I also added explode(). I will add the extra exploding for the issue with 3 and 13 soon, as well as fixing the new line character at the end. Thanks for pointing all that out.

Comment: I added the $user_id line after executes and it is returning the correct variable. Now I just need to know how I put a value into that table that's already created.

Answer (score 0):

As some people mention in your comments you should check the order of the statements.

First you insert the row into your database. On execute the Database will generate the ID which u can retrieve afterwards.

Now you want to add the Deposit_id to the generated entry. Just Update the Entry (`UPDATE users SET deposit_id=:deposit_id WHERE user_id=:user_id;`).

But I think you will get a result, which you don't want.

Is the number in the textfile really the user_id? or just an enumeration? you could just parse it and create an array containing the deposit_ids in the order of the file. Now your can Insert all rows by running one insert per array-entry

Comment: The order has been fixed. I tried the code you posted and that didn't work. The number in the text file is just enumeration. I guess getting rid of that and doing as you said would be more efficient in more than one way. Now I just have the problem of inserting that value into the database.

Comment: ok so you can add an entry into the database without the deposit_id. Which properties does this column have? Is it a foreign key? Or is it just a random string without any link to another table? Maybe you should think about taking this information into another table because you would have 2 entries containing nearly the same information except the deposit_id.